# Can't create new module .Class not Found

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I create file Vv.php in htdocs\kohana\application\vv

**Vv.php**

```
class Vv{
const $r=10;
}
echo 'init';
```

**bootstrap.php**

```
   Kohana::modules(array(
     .....
               'vv' =>APPPATH.'vv'

        ));
echo Vv::$r //Fatal Error Class Vv not Found.
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the class part of a module? If not, there is no need to load it via `Kohana::modules`.

What you can do is move the file to the classes folder:

```
htdocs\kohana\application\classes\Vv.php
```

And then you can access the class from your `bootstrap.php` file like so:

```
Kohana::modules(array(
    .....
));

echo Vv::r
```

Take a look at the [autoloading](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/autoloading) support in Kohana for more information.

Also remember that [class constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) should not start with a `$`, so your Vv class will need to be:

```
class Vv {
    const r = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like to create a module, you better create the vv folder in the modules folder.

```
htdocs\kohana\modules\vv\classes\Vv.php
```

next add the module into the bootstrap file

```
Kohana::modules(array(
   ...
   'vv' =>MODPATH.'vv'
));
```

After you did that your able to acces Vv

```
echo Vv::$r;
```